# Can I create an automatic property (no private member) with get and set code?

Tags: c#, properties, automatic-properties

In c#, I can do this:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

Which is nice. But as soon as I want to do anything in the getter or setter, I have to change it to this:

```
private int foo;
public int Foo {
    get { return foo; }
    set {
        foo = value;
        DoSomething();  // all that other code, just to add this line!
    }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this? I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
public int Foo {
    get;
    set {           
       DoSomething();
    }
}
```

How close can I get to the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this with properties in an existing version of C#, or C# 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is no builtin way to do this.

You could achieve something kind of similar with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/). But I'm not sure its worth the effort.

```
[AfterSet(DoSomething)]
public int Foo {
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I think you're right - it's not worth the effort :P

Comment: could you give some example? Its very interesting for me :)!

Answer (score 0):

With automatic properties, the compiler generates a backing field for you. A custom getter/setter requires that you manually create a backing field to work with. The ability to specify a custom getter/setter on an automatic property would essentially make it act just like a method, since there's nothing to get or set.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer? No. The long answer? Sorry, still no. :) I feel your pain man, but that's the way it is.