# C# internal name behind-the-scenes for getter/setter

Tags: c#, getter-setter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create an automatic property (no private member) with get and set code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664883/can-i-create-an-automatic-property-no-private-member-with-get-and-set-code)
>   [Access automatic property - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323586/access-automatic-property-c-sharp)

I've worked with explicit getters / setters such as

```
private bool myField;
public bool MyField
{  get { return myField; }
   set { myField = value; }
}
```

Now, working with C# .net 4.0, you have the ability to abbreviate such as

```
public bool MyField
{ get; set; }
```

Now, if I want to override only the SET portion, what is the INTERNAL reference I should be referencing... in the first sample, I know I am explicitly referring to the private of "myField", but with the second version, what am I referencing?  Does the compiler just throw an implied "_" such as _MyField as the private side of the element?

Comment: Also [Can I create an automatic property (no private member) with get and set code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664883/can-i-create-an-automatic-property-no-private-member-with-get-and-set-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever the compiler does in this case is an implementation detail which can change in the future without further notice!

Thus I strongly recommend to not make your code depend on such an implementation detail and just use the first option (override both accessors and have field to explicitely back the property) in this case...

Comment: I guess this WAS the answer I was expecting... we can't control something that is automatically handled for us, unless we explicitly use our own internal fields as the place-holders from my original sample.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Parent
    {
        public virtual bool MyField { get; set; }
    }

    class Child : Parent
    {
        public override bool MyField
        {
            //ommitting get portion
            set
            {
                //other custom code goes here
                base.MyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here a class inherits from a class with a property an overrides only the setter.  Alternatively you could override the getter and just leave it as return base.MyField to not change the functionality.

**Edit:**
The issue was raised that when doing this the half that was left out (the get in my example) wouldn't exist in the child class, making the property read/write only.  That is not the case, the half that is left out simply inherits its functionality from its parent.  See the following addition to my example to demonstrate.

```
                Child c = new Child();
                c.MyField = true;
                if (c.MyField)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hi");
                }
```

(This will indeed print "hi", no errors compile or runtime.)

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

You would access the property in the same way, using `MyField`.  However, if you did not want code outside the class to be able to set the property, you can use:

```
public bool MyField { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I knew about the option to private or protected, but trying to SET and attach extra things WITHIN the setting process, if that is ever the case, it appears the old explicit format is required.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Really the only thing I've found the shorthand method really useful for is satisfying an Interface requirement.